# Cantors Theorem Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am working on my own proof for cantors theorem that given any set A, there does not exist a function f: A -> P(A) that is onto. I was wondering if it would be possible to prove this by showing that the cardinality of A is less than P(A) using the proof that the elements of set A is n and P(A) is 2^n so n < 2^n for all natural numbers (by induction). and due to the cardinality being less is it not surjective since not all elements of the codomain are mapped by the domain?

Comment: That works for finite sets...; and [tag:cantor-set] is something else

Comment: is there anyway to make it work for infinite sets as well this way or do i need to completely restart and come up with a different proof

Comment: Trying to make it work for infinite sets is exactly what the usual proof of Cantor's theorem does!

Comment: Im not sure how i can write the usual cantors theorem in my own words without practically saying the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to extend this argument to infinite sets, here's how it goes:

- Let $\alpha$ be the cardinality of $A$.
- Then the cardinality of $\mathcal P(A)$ is $2^\alpha$, essentially by the definition of the notation $2^\alpha$.
- Then we want to use the fact that $\alpha < 2^\alpha$ ...

... but the *definition* (or one equivalent definition) of the assertion "$\alpha < 2^\alpha$" is precisely that there is no onto map from $A$ to $\mathcal P(A)$.

Unlike for finite cardinals, where there are calculus-based or combinatorial proofs of the fact $n<2^n$, we don't have a proof of the assertion $\alpha < 2^\alpha$ for infinite cardinals $\alpha$ that's any simpler than proving the original statement.